# After following all instructions for migrating to Firebase Cloud Functions 1.0, deployment fails

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to migrate my Firebase Cloud Functions installation up to the newly released V1.0.

I've carefully followed all instructions provided at
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff , including including running the updates and also going through every function I have to make sure it reflects the changes in v1 which break old functions.

When I then attempt to run a deploy (for functions only), I get the following error: Error:

> Invalid Firebase app options passed as the first argument to initializeApp() for the app named "[DEFAULT]". The "credential" property must be an object which implements the Credential interface.

Notably, there is a specific mention of no longer needing to provide the credentials in the argument: "firebase-admin is now initialized without any parameters within the Cloud Functions runtime."

My suspicion is the update to Firebase Cloud Functions (npm install firebase-functions@latest --save) didn't succeed. I suspect this because, although there's a lot of activity after that call, the output is just two lines:

```
Brandus@1.0.0 /Users/ajr/Documents/dev/sites/Brandus
└── firebase-functions@1.0.0
```

I've seen another question with the same symptoms: [Cloud Functions Firebase v1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687932/cloud-functions-firebase-v1-0/49688580#49688580). I tried to comment but my reputation is too low.

Edit: code as requested

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require( 'firebase-functions' ) ;

var fs      = require('fs');
var url     = require('url');
var http    = require('http');
var https    = require('https');

// tinycolor2
const tinycolor = require( 'tinycolor2' ) ;
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require( 'firebase-admin' ) ;
//admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
admin.initializeApp();
```

That's all the code up to the point where the error is, with the previous code commented out.

Comment: I want to help, but there isn't any information here that can tell me what's going on. Please update your question with the code for your Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks Jen. I've updated the question with the code as requested.

Comment: Check the contents of `package.json` in your project's functions folder. Does it show `"firebase-functions": "^1.0.0"`?

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder, it does, which I took to mean it had correctly updated so hopefully I was wrong about that.

Comment: And also `"firebase-admin": "^5.11.0"`?

Comment: Yes, that's set correctly as well. As far as I can tell everything is as it should be.

I did notice that the repo of cloud functions v1.0 only offers a Typescript version, whereas I've been using Javascript. I've done a commit of where I was and am now running a test of a fresh functions init using Typescript. So far, so good.

Comment: I was able to successfully deploy after changing my project to use TypeScript and the functions appear to be working correctly after the deployment, so I think I'm good to go for now.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. As suggested by Bob Snyder in one of the comments, I checked my versions in package.json and firebase-admin was still to an old version. After setting it to ^5.11.1 and running "npm install" in the functions folder, I was able to deploy right away. I did not have to change the project to TypeScript.

You could just run `npm install --save firebase-admin@latest` in the functions folder instead. Better this way, no arbitrary version to specify.

Comment: Manually updating my package.json folder helped, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully deploy after changing my project to use TypeScript instead of Javascript. The functions appear to be working correctly after the deployment.

I followed [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#migrating_an_existing_javascript_project_to_typescript) to complete the migration.

It's possible a fresh firebase init would have fixed it even without the migration to typescript, but either way, this worked for me.