# Firebase Functions Deploy: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Functions `JavaScript` version, and when I run `firebase deploy`, I'm getting this error:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> Error: Failed to parse app options file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[object Object]'
>           at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError

This is my `index.js` code up until the line which causes this error:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');


var serviceAccount = require("../functions/file.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com"
});

var config = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "appID",
    storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "number"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

My Node version - **8.11.1**

NPM - **5.6.0**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a bug in `firebase-tools@3.18.1`. Fixed in `3.18.2`.

Run: `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`

Comment: 3.18.2 fixes this.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.18.2

Comment: again with this issue "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0", "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",

Comment: @LukeCarelsen did you fix your issue somehow?

Comment: @AinisSK i cant remember... i dont think so try 3.18.2 like suggested above. sorry :P

Comment: For me, it was that I had forgotten to change a function from firestore to database.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this

> `npm i --save firebase-functions@latest`

Comment: Add explanation to why this will solve the problem.

Comment: @sziraqui It's a bug inside old version so update to the latest should fix this problem

Answer (score -1):

in my case, the file .runtimeconfig.json was not valid JSON because of a trailing comma. So it didnt work with no clue about invalid JSON. I was just lucky to find it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).