# firebase cloud function process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG not working after 1.0.0 with SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

days ago the cloud function is out of beta and the following guide was provided

[Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions Migration Guide: Beta to version 1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#functionsconfigfirebase_removed)

this example was provided to know which project is currently used

```
let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
/* {  databaseURL: 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com',
       storageBucket: 'projectId.appspot.com',
       projectId: 'projectId' }
*/
```

And I tried to add it in my app

```
// import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

export function environment(){
const object:any ={}
let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
    switch(firebaseConfig.projectId){
        case 'app1-id':
            object.projectId = 'app1-id'
            object.keyFilename = 'dev.json'
            break;
        case 'app2-id':
            object.projectId = 'app2-id'
            object.keyFilename = 'staging.json'
            break;
        case 'app3-id':
            object.projectId = 'app3-id'
            object.keyFilename = 'prod.json'
            break;
        default:
            object.projectId = 'app1-id'
            object.keyFilename = 'dev.json'
      }
return object
};
```

but I got the following error

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.environment (/home/hady/Documents/td_functions_outside/functions/lib/helper/env.js:8:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hady/Documents/td_functions_outside/functions/lib/helper/pubSub.js:5:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hady/.npm/_logs/2018-04-06T16_30_50_119Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ deploy:dev: `firebase use dev && npm run deploy`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ deploy:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hady/.npm/_logs/2018-04-06T16_30_50_135Z-debug.log
```

this is the debug file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'deploy:dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy:dev', 'deploy:dev', 'postdeploy:dev' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~predeploy:dev: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~deploy:dev: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~deploy:dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~deploy:dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/hady/Documents/td_functions_outside/functions/node_modules/.bin:/home/hady/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/hady/bin:/home/hady/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~deploy:dev: CWD: /home/hady/Documents/td_functions_outside/functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~deploy:dev: Args: [ '-c', 'firebase use dev && npm run deploy' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~deploy:dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~deploy:dev: Failed to exec deploy:dev script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ deploy:dev: `firebase use dev && npm run deploy`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd /home/hady/Documents/td_functions_outside/functions
16 verbose Linux 4.8.0-32-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "deploy:dev"
18 verbose node v8.10.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error functions@ deploy:dev: `firebase use dev && npm run deploy`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the functions@ deploy:dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and my packge.json got the following

```
"firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",
"firebase-functions": "^1.0.0",
```

with firebase-tools updated

```
hady@hady-HP-Notebook:~/Documents/td_functions_outside/functions$ firebase -V
3.18.1
```

nodejs version

```
hady@hady-HP-Notebook:~/Documents/td_functions_outside/functions$ node -v
v8.10.0
```

Comment: what does your `npm run deploy` script look like? Try to get rid of the `--only functions` flag, it's no longer required.

Comment: `    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",` but running firebase deploy without the flag still gives the same error

Comment: as per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697142/1011766), try downgrading your firebase tools to 3.18.0

Answer (score 0):

thanks to  [JP Lew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011766/jp-lew) who pointed out that the error is related to 
this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697142/1011766)

by downgrading to 3.18.0 things did work again using this command

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools@3.18.0
```

I faced the same exact error in the question after removing the switch case altogether and tried to upload with the projectId hardcoded

Comment: they just posted a hotfix, version 3.18.2. Haven't tested it yet but they claim it fixes this bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.18.2

Comment: will give a try next week (Y)